# Работа lower_bound в C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, c++11, c++17

Помогите разобраться в работе lower_bound:

Есть struct:

```
struct MyStruct
{
  int firstNum;
  int secondNum;
}
```

и есть `vector<MyStruct> myVector`, который хранит структуры.

Информация в myVector:

```
[0] = {firstNum=1 secondNum=1 }
[1] = {firstNum=1 secondNum=2 }
[2] = {firstNum=2 secondNum=1 }
[3] = {firstNum=2 secondNum=2 }
[4] = {firstNum=3 secondNum=1 }
[5] = {firstNum=3 secondNum=2 }
[6] = {firstNum=4 secondNum=1 }
[7] = {firstNum=4 secondNum=2 }
[8] = {firstNum=4 secondNum=3 }
[9] = {firstNum=4 secondNum=4 }
```

Есть задача: при добавлении в myVector располагать объект в нужном месте, то есть: при добавлении 
`MyStrcut ms {2,3}` элементы myVector имели уже след. вид:

```
[2] = {firstNum=2 secondNum=1 }
[3] = {firstNum=2 secondNum=2 }
[4] = {firstNum=2 secondNum=3 }
[5] = {firstNum=3 secondNum=1 }
```

Пытался вот так сделать:

```
auto iter = lower_bound(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), ms, 
                [](const myStruct& mv1, const myStruct& mv2) -> bool {return (mv1.firstNum == mv2.firstNum && mv1.secondNum
< mv2.secondNum); });

myVector.insert(iter, ms);
```

Но это работает неправильно: некоторые элементы добавляет в нужно место, а некоторые в самое начало почему-то.

Comment: Вроде компаратор неправильный, попробуйте `return std::tie(mv1.firstNum, mv1.secondNum) < std::tie(mv2.firstNum, mv2.secondNum);`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat круто, спасибо! Только можно объяснить как оно так получается?

Comment: Это такой трюк для "автоматического" составления компараторов. По сути он делает то же самое, что и компаратор в ответе ниже, но через `std::tie` писать проще, и сложнее ошибиться. Почитайте про `std::tie` и `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас неправильный компаратор.

Должно быть:

```
auto iter = lower_bound(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), ms,
        [](const MyStruct& mv1, const MyStruct& mv2) -> bool {
            return (mv1.firstNum < mv2.firstNum || (mv1.firstNum == mv2.firstNum && mv1.secondNum
            < mv2.secondNum)); 
        });
```

Вот так более читаемо:

```
auto iter = lower_bound(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), ms,
        [](const MyStruct& mv1, const MyStruct& mv2) -> bool {
            if (mv1.firstNum != mv2.firstNum)
                return mv1.firstNum < mv2.firstNum;
            return mv1.secondNum < mv2.secondNum;
        });
```

Дело в том, что в вашем компараторе элементы структуры не сравниваются по первому значению, из-за чего возникают проблемы при сортировке в лексикографическом порядке.

В таком случае нужно при неравенстве firstNum сортировать по нему, в случае равенства сортировать по secondNum.

Comment: спасибо, все работает!